# What is the best practice when importing Contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I will try to clarify my questions with visual aid.

[image: My Usual Import]

The picure above is how I usually import contracts. For example, I import Both `C` and `B` contracts to `A`, even though `B` already imports `C` too.

Recently however, I figured out that a diffrent approach would resault with the same functionality (Picture below)

[image: Works the same]

It seems that because `B` had already imported `C`, it now containts its functionality. Thus I dont have to import both `B` and `C` to `A`, just the `B` contract will do (Picture below)

[image: New approach]

My question is this: What is the right approach, and what are benefits/downsides to each (if there are any). The picures here are simplifications. But in my real project I have dozen contracts, of which many import the other ones. So there is a lot of "import duplications" therefor this seemed like a prudent question to ask.

Comment: There's a section about this in the Solidity docs: [Multiple Inheritance and Linearization](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html?highlight=diamond#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization).

Answer (score 0):

Since `solidity 0.8.x` you can do

```
import { contractA } from "contract/path/1";
import { contractB } from "contract/path/2";
```

This will prevent the shadow import of `contractB` if it is also used in `contracA`

Comment: This code should be in which contract?